# python3 URLError unknown url type http

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to use urllib.request.urlretrieve along with the multiprocessing module to download some files and do some processing on them.  However, each time I try to run my program, it gives me the error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "./thumb.py", line 13, in download_and_convert
    filename, headers = urlretrieve(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 186, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 463, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 486, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1252, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: http>
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./thumb.py", line 27, in <module>
    pool.map(download_and_convert, enumerate(csvr))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 599, in get
    raise self._value
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: http>
```

The url that it seems to choke on is `http://phytoimages.siu.edu/users/vitt/10_27_06_2/Equisetumarvense.JPG`.  Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import Popen
from sys import argv, stdin
import csv
from multiprocessing import Pool
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

def download_and_convert(args):
    num, url_list = args
    url = url_list[0]
    try:
        filename, headers = urlretrieve(url)
    except:
        print(url)
        raise
    Popen(["convert", filename, "-resize", "250x250",\
           str(num)+'.'+url.split('.')[-1]])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csvr = csv.reader(open(argv[1]))

    if(len(argv) > 2): nprocs = argv[2]
    else: nprocs = None

    pool = Pool(processes=nprocs)
    pool.map(download_and_convert, enumerate(csvr))
```

I have no idea why this error is ocurring.  Could it be because I am using multiprocessing?  If anyone could help me, it would be much appreciated.

Edit: This is the first url it tries to process, and it doesn't change the error if I change it.

Comment: You say, "the url that it seems to choke on is...".  Can you verify that?  I see a `print(url)` in your except block, but I don't see this output in your question.  If you isolate the row containing that URL in a separate file, can you reproduce the error? Can you post that row in your question?

Comment: Yes, that is the line that is output from the print in the except block.

Comment: I should also mention that that is the first URL in the file that I process, and if I remove it gives me the same error with the next url.

Comment: It works for me, for the given url, with a simple `from urllib.request import urlretrieve; urlretrieve(" http://phytoimages.siu.edu/users/vitt/10_27_06_2/Equisetumarvense.JPG")`. So there must be something else wrong. Can you do a `print(repr(url))`?

Comment: Hmm.  It gives me `'\ufeffhttp://phytoimages.siu.edu/users/vitt/10_27_06_2/Equisetumarvense.JPG'`.  [\uffef](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm).  Not sure how that got there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from the comments I found the solution.  It appears that the problem was the csv module being tripped up on the byte order mark (BOM).  I was able to fix it by opening the file with `encoding='utf-8-sig'` as suggest [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue7185).

Answer (score 0):

Check this code snippet

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote(':')
'%3A'
```

As you can see urllib interprets the ':' character strangely. Which coincidentally is where your program hangs up on you.

Try `urllib.parse.urlencode()` that should put you on the right track.

Comment: I fail to see how that would help me.  [urlencode is for encoding a dictionary or similar.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)  I'm just trying to get the file at a certain url.